# Python Scikit-Learn ML Model in MATLAB Simulink

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, simulink, system-integration

I have trained a machine learning model in scikit-learn using "ExtraTree Regressor". At the end, I have saved this model as pickle file.

Now I want to use this model in MATLAB/Simulink so that it can be used in the model developed in the Simulink?

How can I bring the scikit-learn model in the Simulink?